# Sitefinity Retrieve All User and Roles from Database

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I know that we can retrieve list of user by using Sitefinity's UserManager class as explained [in this documentation](http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-query-users). However, i'm in a dire need to **retrieve list of all user and roles using plain SQL** which so far i had no success - my superior did not want to use a dummy page to list all user and roles. The only relation i can find is the ownership of a page and it's permission - that end up to roles. But i can't find a direct link from user to roles.

Anyway, i'm using Sitefinity 7.3, please give some insight..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select user_name, r.nme as Role, *
from sf_users as u
join sf_user_link as ul
on u.id = ul.user_id
join sf_roles as r
on r.id = ul.role_id
order by u.user_name
```

Comment: whoa! i really missed `sf_user_link` table, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Today I like this query better.

```
SELECT u.[user_name],
    u.[passwd],
    u.[app_name],
    String_Agg(r.[nme], ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY r.[nme] ASC)  as roles
FROM sf_users AS u
JOIN sf_user_link AS ul ON u.id = ul.user_id
JOIN sf_roles AS r ON r.id = ul.role_id
WHERE u.[is_backend_user] = 1
GROUP BY u.[user_name], u.[passwd], u.[app_name]
ORDER BY u.[user_name]
```